# matlab: cdfplot of relative error

Tags: matlab, plot

[image: CDF plot for relative error.]

The figure shown above is the plot of cumulative distribution function (cdf) plot for relative error (attached together the code used to generate the plot). The relative error is defined as abs(measured-predicted)/(measured). May I know the possible error/interpretation as the plot is supposed to be a smooth curve.

```
 X = load('measured.txt');
 Xhat = load('predicted.txt');
 idx = find(X>0);
 x = X(idx);
 xhat = Xhat(idx);
 relativeError = abs(x-xhat)./(x);
 cdfplot(relativeError);
```

The input data file is a 4x4 matrix with zeros on the diagonal and some unmeasured entries (represent with 0). Appreciate for your kind help. Thanks!

Comment: Why should it be smooth? `cdfplot` only gives a sample CDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot *should* be a discontinuous one because you are using *discrete* data. You are not plotting an analytic function which has an explicit (or implicit) function that maps, say,  x to y. Instead, all you have is at most 16 points that relates x and y.

The CDF only "grows" when new samples are counted; otherwise its value remains steady, just because there isn't any satisfying sample that could increase the "frequency".

You can check the example in Mathworks' [`cdfplot1 documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html) to understand the concept of "empirical cdf". Again, only when you observe a sample can you increase the cdf.

If you really want to "get" a smooth curve, either 1) add more points so that the discontinuous line looks smoother, or 2) find any statistical model of whatever you are working on, and plot the analytic function instead.